# Is there a way for me to get fundamental data from different companies using the investpy package?

Tags: python, json, finance, yahoo-finance, stock

I am trying to pull data from the investpy Python package in order to analyze fundamental data from different companies. I managed to create a script that allows me to view one stock at a time, but I would like to know if it is possible to place several at the same time, with each company on a different line.

Here you can see the packages I pulled:

```
import investpy as inv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (16,8)
```

Here is the script I created in order to pull fundamental data from a specific company (Disney in this example):

```
inv.stocks.get_stock_information(stock='dis', country='united states', as_json=False)
```

I know that with the following code, I can gather all the different tickers in the investpy package:

```
inv.stocks.get_stock_information(stock='dis', country='united states', as_json=False)
```

How can I take advantage of the above script to be able to visualize fundamental data of all companies listed on the American stock exchange in one single table - with each ticker in a different row?

Any help will be really appreciated!